# Javascript Angular factory explanation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.factory('WeatherApi', function($http) {
   var obj = {};

   obj.getLoc = function() {
      return $http.jsonp("http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
   };

   obj.getCurrent = function(city) {
      var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
      var units = "&units=metric";
      var appid = "&APPID=061f24cf3cde2f60644a8240302983f2"
      var cb = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

      return $http.jsonp(api + city + units+ appid + cb);
   };
   return obj
});
```

Can somebody explain what this block of code does? I don't understand what all the different variables are for. What exactly does obj.getLoc do? Does that mean it creates a function. So do they all make up a link at the end and then the json searches for the data that the webpage that is pulled up have?

Comment: These are two functions that are available in the rest of the angular app.  They must be called by some other part of the app.  Read the [angular docs about $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and you will understand what the functions do:  `getLoc` - makes an AJAX call to ipinfo, which is a web service that provides geo-location data about the brower's IP address.  `getCurrent` attempts to make an AJAX call to openweathermap.org for weather information about a given city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code is defining a service for reuse inside your app.

An example usage:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('WeatherApi', function($http) {
  var obj = {};

  obj.getLoc = function() {
    return $http.jsonp("http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
  };

  obj.getCurrent = function(city) {
    var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    var units = "&units=metric";
    var appid = "&APPID=061f24cf3cde2f60644a8240302983f2"
    var cb = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    return $http.jsonp(api + city + units + appid + cb);
  };
  return obj
});

app.controller('someCtrl', function(WeatherApi) {
  var vm = this;
  WeatherApi.getLoc().then(function(response) {
    vm.location = response.data;
    console.log('Your location:' + JSON.stringify(vm.location));
  })
  WeatherApi.getCurrent('nyc').then(function(response) {
    vm.nycWeather = response.data;
    console.log('Weather in NYC:' + JSON.stringify(vm.nycWeather));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="someCtrl as vm">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense now. I have a better understanding of how this works.